# jquery signfield only allows one line on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, canvas, safari

I need to add a signature field on a form, that will be used on an iPad to sign documents.

I need a plugin that will allow multiple signature inputs on the same form.

I found this jQuery plugin "signfield" that works great...

https://github.com/cchantep/jquery.signfield

But it has one huge issue!

On desktop firefox, safari, etc, it works great.

On an iPad, it only allows you to draw one line at a time - if you raise your finger and then try to draw another line, the canvas clears!

That is fine if your signature can be drawn as one continuous line, but that is very unlikely!

On desktop safari it works with no problem - you can draw many lines. But on mobile safari it has this issue.

The issue happens with the demo, so it is an issue with the plugin, not with my implementation of it.

Help!!

Comment: I use the jSignature library for item like this. Check it out. https://willowsystems.github.io/jSignature/#/about/

Comment: This plugin looks decent, but how can you add it to a form so that it submits the data with the form?

Comment: I have it working on submit for many forms and it works on any device and browser. It depends on your needs and how you want to store the signature etc. I actually converting the signature to a base64 string and storing it in a database. Then convert it back for display when needed. I needed encrypted storage and the task did not allow for storing in a file system. What do you want to do with the image upon submit. I wrote several functions to go along with the base library to get everything I wanted as well as overriding some of it's default behavior to meet my exact needs.

Comment: only need to submit base64 string as form field, along with rest of form.

Comment: The library has a built in function "getData", that will give you your base64 string to save. EX: return $("#signature").jSignature("getData", "image");

Comment: Can you create a full answer with code example of a form that will submit base64 data along with the form? I cant get this to submit, and cant add code to a comment.

Comment: In my use case I am doing it with KnockoutJS and AJAX calls, not sure if that will fit your scenario, but I can work something up for you.

Comment: I think we can use getData on form submit, to copy the base64 string to a hidden input field (#signaturefield)? Then base64 data will be submitted in the hidden field? But your documentation is confusing about how to call getData. So help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For jSignature:

*keep in mind I have modified the library a little so that I can print text on the canvas as well so it says what they are agreeing to (I have removed my custome code from the code below to show more of a raw example for the base library)*

HTML:

```
<div id="signature"></div>
```

JS:

Initialize the signature:

```
$("#signature").jSignature({ color: "#000000", "decor-color": "#000000", lineWidth: 2);
```

Check that at least one stroke was performed

```
if ($("#signature").jSignature('getData', 'native', '', '').length === 0) {
    // user has not signed
} else {
    // user has signed
}
```

Get signature image base64 string:

```
model.getSignatureData = function () {
    return $("#signature").jSignature("getData", "image");
}
```

Set observable for signature base64 value:

```
model.SignatureValue(model.getSignatureData()[1]);
```

Then I simply pass the signature value property in the JSON I post to my API